# Sometimes NO is an answer

Tags: discussion

I respectfully disagree with [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/84276) review: the question asks whether something is possible, and the answer says "No". It is indeed an answer.

Either we forbid the "Yes/No" questions altogether, or we allow answers to such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the person that deleted it I would make the argument that an explanation should be given with any statement as to whether something is or isn't possible.

The problem with yes/no answers is they could age with time. For example it might not be possible at the current time to do something but that might change in the future. This is something that might not be immediately obvious unless a reason is given.

Comment: Many answers will age with time, and we can't predict which ones will. For instance, a lot of well written network-related answers became invalid. I'm not implying that the answer you deleted was great, but I think it would've been better if you told the user to improve it rather than deleting it.

Comment: I always add a comment before deleting, but I do sometimes forget that any vote I make in a review queue is binding.